# Determine when matrix has rank $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

> Let $a,b,c,d,e$ be arbitrary complex numbers and define the (symplectic) matrix $$X=\left(\begin{matrix} e & c & 2 a & b \\ -d & \mathbb{i}e & b & c \\-b & a & -e & d\\  a & 2 d & -c & -\mathbb{i}e\end{matrix}\right)$$ where where $i$ denotes a square root of $−1.$ When does the matrix $X$ have rank $2$?

Some potentially useful observations:

- The rank is either $0,2,3$ or $4$;
- Computer simulations over finite fields seem to indicate that if $X$ has rank $2$ then at most one of $a,b,c,d,e$ is zero.
- More simulations show that there are finitely many (possibly just $10$) solutions up to scalar multiples.

If you can't solve it, but have some insight about the difficulty of the question, please let me know!

Comment: Very naive question: in what sense is it symplectic? (It seems that ["usual" symplectic matrices are invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix).)

Comment: @AnneBauval Symplectic in the sense that it's an element of the lie algebra $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ (up to some ordering of the standard basis).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Trying to get my hands on an example made me more hopeful about being able to find a solution. Take $a=1$, $b^5=2$, $c=b^2$, $d=-b^2/2$, $e=0$.

Comment: For me, this doesn't have rank $2$. The determinant then is $(b^3 - 6b^2 - 2b + 8)/2$. This is nonzero for all fifth roots of $2$. So the rank is $4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, should be $d=-b^4/2$

Comment: Indeed, then it works! The kernel then is generated by $(2,0,b^3,-2b^2)$ and $(0,1,-b^2,b)$. So the rank is $2$. This can be generalized (take different $a$ and change $b^5=2$). Do you have an example with rank $1$, too?